# Condtional window onload based on selected menu side

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

I have the following landing page
[image]

When the page loads I want the left page to be active as shown unfortunately for now when the page loads both the left menu and the right menu are active.If I click on the right menu it does not work.

**Hosted site**
`https://leskoy.bonusgigs.com/`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('scarves').className = '';
  document.getElementsByClassName('rightlinks')[0].className = 'active'
};

function openLeftMenu(menu) {
  if (menu === 'scarves') {
    document.getElementById('scarves').className = '';
    document.getElementById('stockists').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('scarvesBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('stockistsBtn').className = '';
  }
  if (menu === 'stockists') {
    document.getElementById('stockists').className = '';
    document.getElementById('scarves').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('stockistsBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('scarvesBtn').className = '';

  }

}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('why').className = '';
  document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].className = 'active'
};



function openMenu(menu) {
  if (menu === 'why') {
    document.getElementById('why').className = '';
    document.getElementById('process').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('whyBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('processBtn').className = '';


  }

  if (menu === 'process') {
    document.getElementById('process').className = '';
    document.getElementById('why').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('processBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('whyBtn').className = '';


  }

  if (menu === 'connect') {
    document.getElementById('connect').className = '';
    document.getElementById('process').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('connectBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('whyBtn').className = '';

  }

  if (menu === 'faq') {
    document.getElementById('faq').className = '';
    document.getElementById('process').className = 'content';

    document.getElementById('faqBtn').className = 'active';
    document.getElementById('whyBtn').className = '';

  }




}
```

```html
<div class="leftpane">
  <nav style="margin-top: 30px;" id="menu">
    <a class="tablinks " onclick="openMenu('why')" id="whyBtn">
      <h2 class="cooler">why<span class="arrow"></span></h2>
    </a>
    <a class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu('process')" id="processBtn">
      <h2 class="cooler">process<span class="arrow"></span></h2>
    </a>


  </nav>
</div>
<div class="middlepane">
  <div class="content" id="why"></div>
  <div class="content" id="process"></div>
  <div class="content" id="scarves"></div>
  <div class="content" id="stockists"></div>
</div>

<div class="rightpane">
  <div style="margin-top: 60%;">
    <nov id="menu">
      <a class="rightlinks" onclick="openLeftMenu('scarves')" id="scarvesBtn">
        <h2 class="drool">scarves<span class="arrow"></span></h2>
      </a>
      <a class="rightlinks" onclick="openLeftMenu('stockists')" id="stockistsBtn">
        <h2 class="drool">stockists<span class="arrow"></span></h2>
      </a>
    </nov>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use onload but use `addEventListener('load', () => {})`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: You are overwriting your onload. Just have one and use eventListener as suggested but on "DOMContentLoaded" and not load

Comment: Also please use the classList api: `document.getElementById('scarves').classList.toggle("content",menu === 'scarves')` etc

Comment: @mplungjan I would appreciate if you illustrutrate how you pass the elements within the onload function inot the  addEventListener('load', () => {})

Comment: You don't have to pass anything, and you don't have a onload function. And for the event to use that depends on your usecase, it's just an example but you can use DOMContentLoaded if you need to, it does not really matters, if you have a lot of images or subframes that can be better to use DOMContentLoaded since it will trigger faster than load

Comment: @Lk77 I will git it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do more than one thing in the onload.
Also note how I cache the elements and address the first of the class using querySelector

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const scarves = document.getElementById('scarves');
  const scarvesBtn = document.getElementById('scarvesBtn');
  const stockists = document.getElementById('stockists');
  const stockistsBtn = document.getElementById('stockistsBtn');
  const why = document.getElementById('why');
  const rightlinks = document.querySelector('.rightlinks');
  const tablinks = document.querySelector('.tablinks')

  const openLeftMenu = menu => {
    scarves.classList.toggle("content", menu === 'stockists')
    scarvesBtn.classList.toggle("active", menu === 'scarves')
    stockists.classList.toggle("content", menu === 'scarves')
      .classList.toggle("active", menu === 'stockists')
  }
  // init
  scarves.classList.remove("active");
  why.classList.remove("active");
  rightlinks.classList.add("active");
  tablinks.classList.add("active");
});
```